# Why is sort functionality not using the index I created (even with the use of $hint)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created and ascending and descending index for `a`

`db.getCollection('objectlists').createIndex( { a: 1 } )`

`db.getCollection('objectlists').createIndex( { a: -1 } )`

When I use this index in the `find` functionality, it works perfectly even on large amount of data

`db.getCollection('objectlists').find({a: {$gt: 0}})` --> returns instantly.

However, when I use it for sort such as:

`db.getCollection('objectlists').find().sort({a: 1})`, I get:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
    "code" : 96,
    "codeName" : "OperationFailed"
}
```

I have even tried adding hint:

`db.getCollection('objectlists').find().sort({a: 1}).hint({a: 1});`

But I end up getting the same error. I tried also using `ensureIndex()` before running this query, but still did not help solve the error. What is the issues? Am I misunderstanding how index sorting works?

The output of `db.getCollection('objectlists').find().sort({a: 1}).explain()` is

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "App.objectlists",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {},
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "a" : 1.0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "a" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "a_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "a" : [ 
                                "a"
                            ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "a" : [ 
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
```

Comment: What does `db.getCollection('objectlists').find().sort({a: 1}).explain()` print? Also, which MongoDB version are you using? Lastly, one index on a field should be enough. MongoDB will use it for sorts in either direction.

Comment: @dnickless the version is: 4.0.2.
I added what explain was printing.

Comment: `SORT_KEY_GENERATOR` is what we don't want here - it's an in-memory sort, hence the error message. One reason why this could happen is perhaps the fact that all your documents are already in memory or something? Do you have a very small collection? And is your ´a´ field very large or is there anything else special about your test documents? Are you storing arrays in `a`? `isMultiKey: true` would indicate this. But the output of that has been wrong already in the past at times: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15958